# How can I take date from user and set it as default to check the deadline in app

Tags: java, android

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXQGA.png)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1DN6.png)

I want to take the date from screen 1 and cast it as a string so that it gets compared with the current date and then generate a Toast as shown in screen 2.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date strDate= null;
    try {
        strDate = sdf.parse(my_date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deadline over.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deadline not over.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

here my_date is `String my_date="dd/mm/yyyy";`

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXQGA.png) and [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1DN6.png) are both different activities.
I tried: gettext(textView) and store it in a String but that didn't work.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: thank you @OleV.V. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

use [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker).

From the `DatePicker` you can create a `Date` object like this:

```
public static Date getDate(DatePicker dp){
    int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = dp.getMonth();
    int year =  dp.getYear();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

and then compare it with current Date :

```
Date userEnteredDate = getDate(dp);
if(Calendar.getInstance().getTime() > userEnteredDate){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deadline over.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Example xml for DaterPicker:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```